# Missing Visual Studio Installer in Setup & Deployment category

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to ask a question. It is missing the "Visual Studio Installer" in Setup and Deployment. How can I do this. Please give me advice.

[image]

Like this ->
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htt8F.png)

Comment: If someone know, please leave me link.

Comment: What is exactly "Visual Studio Installer" to your mind and why do you expect it there?

Comment: "Setup Wizard" to create a setup for a window application.

Answer (score 0):

for VS 2015 you can download [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

Visual Studio setup projects (vdproj) are not supplied with VS 2012
here is a solutions for you:

You must register to download the InstallShield Limited Edition. After you complete the following procedure, the InstallShield Limited Edition Project template appears in Visual Studio.

On the menu bar, choose File, New, Project.

Expand the Other Project Types node.

Expand the Setup and Deployment node.

Choose Enable InstallShield Limited Edition, and then choose the OK button.

Choose the Download Now link.

this steps were taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx)

Comment: I did but it show error like this "Microsoft Visual Studio is required, but it is not installed on this computer. Please install it and retry.
". What can i do ?

Comment: what version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: Now, I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012".

Comment: ok try this [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-690586.AdvancedInstallerforVisualStudio2012)